# wget does not recurse when piping the output to stdout

Tags: wget

I want to download webpages recursively and pipe the output to a filter. I am using:

```
wget -qm -O- http://mywebsite.com/initialpath.php | ./filter
```

But `wget` stops downloading after the first page and waits for input instead of parsing the webpage and downloading linked files.  It works if I save the output to a file with `-O filename` but I want to handle the webpages on the fly with a filter.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure the `./filter` does not block here?

Comment: I am sure... I studied the source code for `wget` and found the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I does not seem possible to achieve my goal with current versions of `wget`.

After studying the source code for `wget` version 1.18, I came to these conclusions:

- `wget` cannot recurse if it does not store the downloaded files, at least temporarily as for `--spider`.
- When passed `-O filename`, it keeps appending to `filename` and reparses the whole file after each download, loading it completely in memory (or mapping it). This is very cumbersome and inefficient.
- When passed `-O-`, it pipes the downloaded file to `stdout` and attempts to reload `-` to look for more urls to fetch... Which causes `stdin` to be read for this purpose. This is a side effect of the implementation.

I wrote a patch to add a more sensible piping option, relying on `--spider` to download html and css files for recursive operation and piping only these files before they are removed. I will publish the patch when it is reasonably tested and documented.